# how to disable DEBUG in log4j?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, logging, log4j

need your help, I have log4j.properties like this

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=stdout, file


# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Redirect log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=${catalina.home}/logs/Admin.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

and this is my Controller

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @RequestMapping(value="/addedc", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json", headers = "content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    public @ResponseBody Status_new addedc(@RequestBody installasimodel edc){
        log.info("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< START ADDEDC >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
        log.debug("qqqqqqqqqqqqqq");
        List<installasimodel>mapusr = null;
        try{
            insta.addistlsi(edc);
            log.info(new Status_new(1, "Sukses!"));
            return new Status_new(1, "Sukses!");
        }catch(Exception mapi){
            log.info(new Status_new(0, mapi.getMessage()));
            log.info("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< STOP ADDEDC >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
            return new Status_new(0, mapi.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I want to show "INFO" in the file .log, but why DEBUG also appear? thus fulfilling the page.This example logs generated

```
....
....
2016-02-05 15:14:58 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:185 - Public object - authentication not attempted
2016-02-05 15:14:58 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:323 - /ins-server-insta/ins-list-all-insta-installasi reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2016-02-05 15:14:58 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:838 - DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher' processing GET request for [/admin-teknikal/ins-server-insta/ins-list-all-insta-installasi]
2016-02-05 15:14:58 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:246 - Looking up handler method for path /ins-server-insta/ins-list-all-insta-installasi
2016-02-05 15:14:58 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:251 - Returning handler method [public java.util.List<com.bni.edc.model.installasimodel> com.bni.edc.controller.instaController.getInsta()]
2016-02-05 15:14:58 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:249 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'instaController'
2016-02-05 15:14:58 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:925 - Last-Modified value for [/admin-teknikal/ins-server-insta/ins-list-all-insta-installasi] is: -1
2016-02-05 15:14:58 INFO  nanda:63 - <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< START ALL INSTALLASI LIST >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
2016-02-05 15:14:58 DEBUG AbstractTransactionImpl:160 - begin
2016-02-05 15:14:58 DEBUG LogicalConnectionImpl:226 - Obtaining JDBC connection
2016-02-05 15:14:58 DEBUG DriverManagerDataSource:142 - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bni]
2016-02-05 15:14:58 DEBUG LogicalConnectionImpl:232 - Obtained JDBC connection
2016-02-05 15:14:58 DEBUG JdbcTransaction:69 - initial autocommit status: true
2016-02-05 15:14:58 DEBUG JdbcTransaction:71 - disabling autocommit
2016-02-05 15:14:58 DEBUG SQL:109 - SELECT * FROM istlsi_edc_tkn_tebel WHERE sts!='1' ORDER BY id_istlsi_tkn DESC
2016-02-05 15:14:58 DEBUG Loader:951 - Result set row: 0
2016-02-05 15:14:58 DEBUG Loader:1485 - Result row: EntityKey[com.bni.edc.model.installasimodel#22344444]
2016-02-05 15:14:58 DEBUG Loader:951 - Result set row: 1
2016-02-05 15:14:58 DEBUG Loader:1485 - Result row: EntityKey[com.bni.edc.model.installasimodel#232323]
2016-02-05 15:14:58 DEBUG TwoPhaseLoad:160 - Resolving associations for [com.bni.edc.model.installasimodel#22344444]
2016-02-05 15:14:58 DEBUG TwoPhaseLoad:286 - Done materializing entity [com.bni.edc.model.installasimodel#22344444]
2016-02-05 15:14:58 DEBUG TwoPhaseLoad:160 - Resolving associations for [com.bni.edc.model.installasimodel#232323]
2016-02-05 15:14:58 DEBUG TwoPhaseLoad:286 - Done materializing entity [com.bni.edc.model.installasimodel#232323]
2016-02-05 15:14:58 DEBUG AbstractTransactionImpl:175 - committing
2016-02-05 15:14:58 DEBUG AbstractFlushingEventListener:149 - Processing flush-time cascades
2016-02-05 15:14:58 DEBUG AbstractFlushingEventListener:189 - Dirty checking collections
2016-02-05 15:14:58 DEBUG AbstractFlushingEventListener:123 - Flushed: 0 insertions, 0 updates, 0 deletions to 2 objects
2016-02-05 15:14:58 DEBUG AbstractFlushingEventListener:130 - Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 0 collections
2016-02-05 15:14:58 DEBUG EntityPrinter:114 - Listing entities:
2016-02-05 15:14:58 DEBUG EntityPrinter:121 - com.bni.edc.model.installasimodel{tngl_qrcode=null, tngl_sbm_istlsi=null, tngl_sbmit=2016-02-04, ttd_mrchn=null, kde_pos_sls=0, own=BN, mid=23232323, hp_penerima=null, id_istlsi_tkn=48, id_wlyh=1, tid=232323, id_spv=0, foto_istlsi=null, sc=1, ttd_istlsi=null, alamat_mrchn=asasa, jam=null, kde_pos=0, sn=null, ket_istlsi=sdsddsdsdsdsd, kde_pos_tkn=null, ntf_adm=0, ttd=null, ms=null, id_tkn=28, koor_lat=null, gprs_id=null, tngl_chck_adm=null, version=null, koor_long=null, sts=0, foto=null, phone=23232, nm_penerima=daa, sts_edc=0, id_usr_adm_sls=0, own_mrchn=null, nm_mrchn=dsds, id_usr_sls=0}
2016-02-05 15:14:58 DEBUG EntityPrinter:121 - com.bni.edc.model.installasimodel{tngl_qrcode=null, tngl_sbm_istlsi=null, tngl_sbmit=2016-02-04, ttd_mrchn=null, kde_pos_sls=0, own=BN, mid=20397878789, hp_penerima=null, id_istlsi_tkn=49, id_wlyh=3, tid=22344444, id_spv=0, foto_istlsi=null, sc=1, ttd_istlsi=null, alamat_mrchn=jl.soedirman kav.04, jam=null, kde_pos=0, sn=null, ket_istlsi=butuh cepat dan segera, kde_pos_tkn=null, ntf_adm=0, ttd=null, ms=null, id_tkn=27, koor_lat=null, gprs_id=null, tngl_chck_adm=null, version=null, koor_long=null, sts=0, foto=null, phone=09787879, nm_penerima=yuyun, sts_edc=0, id_usr_adm_sls=0, own_mrchn=null, nm_mrchn=laksana baru, id_usr_sls=0}
2016-02-05 15:14:58 DEBUG JdbcTransaction:113 - committed JDBC Connection
2016-02-05 15:14:58 DEBUG JdbcTransaction:126 - re-enabling autocommit
2016-02-05 15:14:58 DEBUG LogicalConnectionImpl:246 - Releasing JDBC connection
2016-02-05 15:14:58 DEBUG LogicalConnectionImpl:264 - Released JDBC connection
2016-02-05 15:14:58 INFO  nanda:71 - <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< STOP ALL INSTALLASI LIST >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
....
```

how can I disable DEBUG ?

Answer (score 1):

Change DEBUG to INFO

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, file
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you are using Log4j **v1.x**...

In your configuration `properties` you're only configuring appenders (root logger output will be sent to `stdout` end `file`):

```
log4j.rootLogger=stdout, file
```

but you aren't specifying logging level (default level is `DEBUG`), so **everything** is logged on your appenders.

To set a specific logging level you need to configure it properly. In particular, if you need to log only from `INFO` level to `FATAL` level, you have to set this:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, file
```

Take a look: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html

---

**UPDATE**

If you need to log Hibernate activities (only `INFO` level) you also need to set these configurations:

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO, stdout, file
```

Comment: I have changing into "log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, file",if I want to appear Hibernate what can I do?

Comment: @Zia what do you mean? do you want to log hibernate activities?

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the Logging Level in your `log4j.xml`.

Set your Logger level to `INFO` like this:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, file
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this `log4j.rootLogger=stdout, file` to `log4j.rootLogger= INFO, stdout, file`

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution A: Initialize root logger with level INFO for stdout and file

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO,stdout,file
```

#### Solution B: Set the log level for specified components

```
log4j.logger.com.endeca=INFO
```